# apache only changing to trailing slash with http not https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've tried about 10 solutions so far, gone thru almost all the serverfault and stackoverflow related questions. lost some hair etc.

My site used to be http://example.com
and is now https://example.com

All links to http://example.com/filename.html
turn in to https://example.com/filename.html

All links to http://example.com/directory
turn in to https, and adds the slash: https://example.com/directory/

and https://example.com/directory
also adds the slash, https://example.com/directory/

But all links (and this is most of my external incomming links) to http://example.com/directory/

404 !

Here is my latest attempt at the default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin support@example.com

        DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com/public_html/
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]

        <Directory />
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /srv/www/example.com/public_html/>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined env=!dontlog
</VirtualHost>
```

heres the start of my ssl.conf:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin support@example.com
        ServerName example.com:443
        ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

        DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com/public_html

        <Directory />
                <IfModule mod_expires.c>
                     ExpiresActive off
                </IfModule>
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /srv/www/example.com/public_html>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

                ExpiresActive On
                ExpiresDefault "access plus 12 hours"
                ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 10 months"
                ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 10 months"
                ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 10 months"
                ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 months"
                ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 months"
                ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 monthss"
                ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 10 months"
                FileETag MTime Size
```

Comment: You disabled the Indexes option, but do you have a DirectoryIndex directive?

Answer (score 0):

Try a blanket redirect in the non-ssl directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This should forward everything and anything from http://example.com to https://example.com

Answer (score 0):

This was a tough one, I had another site-enabled .conf file that was redirecting an old subdomain to a folder name within the main ssl website.
Some tutorial I followed suggested that when I do this I should use serverAlias as the main website, bad idea, apache was doing the redirect specified in the subdomain.conf as if it were the main-ssl.conf website. The clue was in the log file, the 404's were for:

```
    /old-subdomain-redirect/browser-Asked-Folder/
```

So looks like using the same ServerAlias within another .conf file can merge the directives.

What was making it difficult was the browser was caching the redirects without asking the server, so when I had disabled all other sites-enabled, I was seeing the same results :-/